# Can DIBAL-H reduce carboxylic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

**Question :** Can DIBAL-H (Diisobutylaluminium hydride) reduce carboxylic acid?

According to "March's Advanced Organic Chemistry" (by Jerry March),  acid can be reduced upto aldehyde using DIBAL-H. But on the other hand, "Solomons & Fryhle Organic Chemistry" and "Organic Chemistry by Jonathan Clayden" this isn't possible (though not said explicitly).

I am confused now. Can someone please confirm that whether this reduction is possible or not?

Comment: But still there is no explanation and answer for this, I will thank full if any one can give proper explanation for it

Comment: Please share the relevant page numbers from the books you have mentioned so that users who have them can check it too. Thanks.